# How to create a random quest. picking system in Xcode

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray

Here's my question---

I want to create a Question System that helps me to pick out a random Question.  I have two parameters: how many questions to ask, and how many unique questions.

For example, I have 6 unique Questions   (1,2,3,4,5,6)

And I have to ask questions 10 times     (1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4)

What logic I need is

1. I want it be random
2. "Every question should been picked at least one times"
3. "Each question shouldn't repeat at any time" example: (2,6,6,3,4,1,)<---the 6type of question is repeated at place 2 and 3.

My logic is poor....

Can anyone write me a Method can return an Array that contains like (3,6,5,1,2,4,6,2,1,3)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make an array called 'chosen' which is the same size as the question array. Set each value of the chosen array to 0. Each time you randomly choose a question, accept it only if its chosen[n] value is 0, and then set chosen[n] to 1. When all values of the chosen array equal 1, then reset all values to 0.